# controlling an LED bulb using WiFi

Tags: c

im looking to switch on or off an LED bulb using the WiFi connection via a smartphone app.i tried various websites and i could not find a suitable answer for this.i just wanted to know how to interface the WiFi receiver with the microcontroller in the bulb and then control it via a application in android or iOS.
thankyou

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. However, if you come up against any specific programming related problems during your project, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: What will switch on the LED bulb? How are you connecting the bulb to the WiFi device? You may think of controlloers like RaspberryPi.

Comment: Probably (almost certainly) a question better suited to the Arduino forums: http://forum.arduino.cc/

Comment: this has nothing to do with the `c` tag

Answer (score 1):

This question is I think too broad, though I am trying to give you an idea, what you need and what your approach should be.

You need two endpoints one on your iPhone and the other in your led device. In the led device you need a program running on a micro-controller which will receive and send packets via wifi adapter and will be able to process those packets accordingly.

On the other end the iOS app would create a socket (or some other communication endpoint) and send some packet using some protocal e.g. TCP.

You may get a general tutorial on socket [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server). But keep in mind that this tutorial uses iPhone as client, but in your case it will be a server.